# Force npm to use only private registry

Tags: npm, npm-registry

We are using npm with a private registry. 
I know the usage of a private registry is possible by:

- including it in the .nmprc file (registry=[registry])
- as parameter via cli by "npm install --registry==[registry]

If resolving the dependencies via the private registry fails, npm uses the central artifactory ( https://registry.npmjs.org/ ). I want to supress this behaviour and only allow the private registry. If the dependency is not in the private registry, it should fail and don't use a fallback. Is this possible?

Comment: I also like to know how to do it?